# Parameter not found exception when including a parameter into another

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

```
parameters:
     bundles:
        liveupload: 'GabrielLiveUploadBundle' 
     entities:
        liveupload_post: "%bundles.liveupload%:Post"
```

This code throws the error

> ParameterNotFoundException: The parameter "entities" has a dependency
>   on a non-existent parameter "bundles.liveupload".

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You are creating a parameter called `bundles` that is an array with a key of `liveupload`. To create it as a single line parameter you would need to use `bundles.liveupload: 'GabrielLiveUploadBundle'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
parameters:
    bundles.liveupload: 'GabrielLiveUploadBundle' 
    entities:
        liveupload_post: "%bundles.liveupload%:Post"
```